# how can i set link to image in javascript??? in the following code

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, loading

I want to know how can i add image or gif file in inverted commas `''` in this line `_("status").innerHTML = '';` (line no. 13 in actual code)

I would be really very thankful to you, if you can answer this question!

my actual code is as follows:-

```
<script>

function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = '';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 _("status").innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='photos/picture.jpg' border=0/></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
_("status").innerHTML = '<img src="your image url" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

This shold help you...

```
_("status").innerHTML = "<img src=\"img_file.gif\"/> Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple,

```
_('status').innerHTML='<a href="#"><img src="your_image.jpg"></a>';
```